# Cellular automata - what to do on boundary cell?

Tags: java, cellular-automata

I'm trying to implement a cellular automata simulating wave behaviour. I'm using Von Neumann neighbourhood with `r=2` [like here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood)

My question is: How should I count state of the cell on the boundary?

For example: I'm having an array `a`, and I want to count value of `a[0][0]`.

States of cells are floats in range of (-1,1) where 0 is land. On "regular" cells I can take states of neighbours, but when there are fewer neighbours (<12) the result is just wrong, and "generates" a new wave.

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: One option is to treat the plane in which your cells live as a torus where the top edge connects to the bottom edge and the right edge to the left edge. so -1,-1 is the same as your top right corner (assuming bottom left origin)

Comment: That's a decision you have to make yourself. You can do this like *Nokia*'s *Snake* where the left of the left boundary is the right boundary. Others implement it as if the border cells are always false.

Comment: @pvg Thats seems to be a good solution, but only if I would like to simulate open sea behaviour. In the future I'll have to add a coast (values=0) which should not affect the waves on the other side

Comment: @manetsus: https://github.com/durden2/waterSimulation/tree/master/src/cellularAutomata - here is my repo, sorry for the bad code quality

Comment: @Nevaan this is very much dependent on the particulars of your CA and how you determine the 'fitness' or quality of your results, none of which we know anything about. Perhaps you want the walls to act as (potentially inelastic) reflectors? Or perfect absorbers? There just isn't any obvious way this can be answered given what you've provided.

Comment: @pvg Sorry for not giving enough information. I would like 'borders' of CA (area out of my array) to behave like a perfect absorber, and cells with value 0 - walls or land - to behave like reflector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions to your problem.

1. Periodic boundary condition : consider the lattice as a torus and use a modulo to loop your cells.

Example: a[-1][0] = a[n-2][0]

Good side: this avoid any "border-effect" by making the lattice invariant by translation, which should lead to a more natural evolution.
Bad side: at smaller scales, this can have undesired effects such as resonance.

This approach is particularly suitable if you wanna do a quantitative study of your model, such as phase transition, mean-field, etc..

2. Inert boundary condition : consider the border of your lattice to have an absorbing rule, that is, they simulate "external" cells which always have the same inert states.

Example: a[-1][0] = 10e-6 or so because 0 means land.

Good side: you avoid resonance effects.
Bad side: potentially border-effects, as well as the absence of external source of waves.

This approach is better-suited for qualitative uses: checking the validity of your implementation, looking for model artefacts (e.g. a maëlstrom-like pattern?) or simply presenting a system that looks organic for an observer.

3. Be creative ...

Example : All border cells are land (0).

Comment: What is meant by resonance in this context (for modular border condition)?